# Using puts in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have this code in controller:

```
array = ["asd", "asd", "asd"]
    @print = array.each do |i|
       puts "Random text #{i}"
    end
```

And now I want to print it in some pages view like show.html.erb:

```
<%= @print >
```

And I get this: `["asd", "asd", "asd"]`  But In controller I sayd to `puts` each object in array, but it is not doing it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `puts` method is for printing a string to the console. If you wanted to set each of the values of the array to a certain value in order to print it out later, you should use `#map`.

```
array = ['asd', 'asd', 'asd']
@print = array.map { |i| "Random text #{i}" }
```

Now, in your corresponding view, you should add:

```
<% @print.each do |val| %>
  <%= val %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Allright. And now if I print it, how can I make it appear as not a array. Currently it attaches the random text infront of the value and then print the whole array again.  If I use @print.each ,  it still gives the array..

Comment: @Veske Added that detail in the answer above

Comment: Allright, now it does it like I want it to at first: 
`Random text asd Random text asd Random text asd ["Random text asd", "Random text asd", "Random text asd"]`

But after that it prints the array on top of it all. Why is that?

Comment: @veske Are you doing `<%= @print ..` instead of `<% @print ...` there?

Comment: That's exactly what was wrong. Thank you! Got the whole thing working now in the app !!

Comment: Glad it helped you to get sorted. :)

Answer (score 3):

`puts` prints to the stdout (standard output) that, in the majority of cases, corresponds to the console where you started the Rails server.

Check the console and you will find, in the middle of the request logs, also the result of the `puts` statement.

A better way to print out something from the console is to use the Rails logger, especially if you want such output to be logged in the logs in production.

```
Rails.logger.info "message"
```

Assuming it's just for debugging purpose, then it's fine to use `puts` (or `p`).

Answer (score 2):

You should be doing the looping in your view.  This helps maintain the separation between your application logic and your view code.

**Controller**

```
@array = ["asd", "asd", "asd"]
```

**View**

```
<% @array.each do |i|
  <%= i %>    # No need to use the puts method here
<% end %>
```

Comment: Thank you so much, your code works for me man, but you need to update this line   
   `<% @array.each do | i | %>`

Answer (score 0):

it seems that the variable @print is the array.  The controller is run once per load of the page and then will output its contents at the end to the view.  Plus, "puts" is for printing a string to the console.  You should put the loop in question in the view like this:

```
<% @array.each do |i| %>
  <%= i @>
<% end %>
```